# Bash: String variable that includes literal single quotes

Tags: bash, quotes, string-literals

Just trying to get a `mysqldump` script working with a backup user password that contains spaces; if I had a choice, I'd just change it, but I don't.

Head is spinning trying to sort out the wonderful world of Bash and quotes, just need the following to execute...

`mysql -u backupuser -p'This is a terrible password with spaces' -e ...`

...but with a variable instead:

`MYPASS="'This is a terrible password with spaces'"` (<-- this, and about 9,307 variations I've tried do not work)

`mysql -u backupuser -p$MYPASS -e ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing the password via command line is considered insecure as other users could see the password in plain text either using `ps afx` or the `/proc` file system. I've recently wrote a [blog post](http://www.metashock.de/2013/07/safely-pass-mysql-credentials-to-mysqldump-in-a-script/) regarding this topic.

However, to make the command *just working* it needs double quotes `"` around `$MYPASS` to prevent bash from interpreting the space-sepearated password as multiple args:

```
MYPASS="foo bar password"
mysql -u backupuser -p"$MYPASS" -e ...
```

But I would highly recommend a solution like the following, which uses [`expect`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) to pass the password to `mysqldump`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# mysql credentials and connection data
db_host="localhost"
db_name="testdb"
db_user="jon"
db_pass="secret"

# I'm using a here-document to pass commands to expect. 
# (the commands could be stored in a file as well)
expect <<EOF
# disable command output
log_user 0
# start the mysqldump process
spawn mysqldump -h$db_host -u$db_user -p $db_name
# wait for the password prompt
expect "password:"
# send the password (mind the \r)
send "$db_pass\r"
# enable output again
log_user 1
# echo all outout until the end
expect eof
EOF
```

`expect` will pass the password in a way like a human user would do: It writes it to stdin of `mysqldump` after being prompted for it. If you make sure that other users cannot access the except script, they'll have no option to see the password in plain text.

Comment: Hate to nitpick but can you clarify the comment "using cat together with an here document to pass..."?

Comment: @gravyface have you ever written a file on the command line without an editor, using `cat <<EOF > file` ? I ask because if you know that you'll know what I mean.. Btw, I admit that this could be done even without `cat` only with an here-doc.

Comment: I have not.  Just the phrase "an here" threw me off.

Comment: @gravyface I've corrected spelling. (I'm not a native speaker) Is it more understandable now?

Comment: Ah ok, so "here" is a colloquial/informal term.  Wasn't sure what you meant there; looked like a word was missing.

Comment: Interesting how such minor changes make the text more readable for native speakers. I really appreciate such comments. I have still to learn so much in english!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34000/discussion-between-gravyface-and-hek2mgl)

Comment: @gravyface It's ok to chat will be there in 10 minutes

Answer (score 1):

i would go with

```
mysql -u backupuser -p -e ...
```

and provide the password at the prompt, rather than putting it into the the cmdline args.

if you specify the password as an argument to `mysql`, virtually every user who is logged into the machine while you run the script can get the password using a simple `ps aux`

Comment: Hard to automate if typing the password is required. `expect` will help here. check my answer

Comment: @hek2mgl true, though OP didn't really say what the script was to be used for. i mainly wanted to point out that using the password like suggested by the OP is inherently insecure. and yes, `expect` is a good solution if you need the script to run on it's own.

Comment: OK. if the script should not being automatically called, meaning it is just thought for interactive usage, your solution is the best, as it is not required to store the password in plain text at all.. +1 ;) But as the user tells about backup issues, I don't expect that it is meant for interactive usage. However, we don't know so far